# Born rule and Feynman propagators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-interpretations, virtual-particles

Let us assume that we want to describe the full process of photon emission by electron A and absorption by electron B.

Therefore electron B must be on the forward lightcone of electron A.

In the normal forwards in time description a virtual photon propagates from A to B depositing a certain amount of energy and momentum onto electron B.

But does this process alone also describe the recoil of electron A?

Should one also include the backwards-in-time virtual photon which propagates from B to A depositing an equal amount of negative energy and momentum back onto electron A?

Between measurements no-one is "looking" at a quantum system so in the spirit of "what isn't prohibited is compulsory" maybe it evolves both forwards and backwards in time.

One could say that the product of the forward-in-time and backward-in-time propagators give the full probability of photon emission by A and absorption by B.

Is this where the Born rule comes from (as in John Cramer's TIQM)?

Comment: I think, when electron A emits the photon, it already experiences all the change of energy and momentum (due to photon creation and emission) needed to satisfy momentum conservation etc. No need for backwards process.

Comment: But if electron A "measures" the photon's energy and momentum when it recoils then the photon will be real (with a definite energy and momentum) rather than virtual as it should be due to its finite lifetime.